# .htaccess help needed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is the difference between

`RedirectPermanent` and `RewriteRule`

i came across a code

```
RewriteRule ^coaching/([^/]+)/?$ search_result.php?categoryName=$1  [NC,L]
```

another setting is

```
RedirectPermanent "/coaching/Run to live"   http://www.example.com/coaching
```

The former rule breaks my setting i can't remove that too.

It makes the output like this

```
http://www.example.com/coaching?categoryName=Run%20to%20live
```

What should be added so that without changing first code i can acheive the result

```
http://www.example.com/coaching
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RewriteRule directive comes from [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), whereas the RedirectPermanent directive comes from [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html).

In this scenario, they don't play well together. The RedirectPermanent uses the original URL */coaching/Run to live*, but sees the modified query string *?categoryName=Run%20to%20live* created by your RewriteRule. While this is kind of unexpected, it's a gotcha of using mod_rewrite and mod_alias together in a per-directory (.htaccess) context.

Since you need mod_rewrite for your original RewriteRule anyway, the best option is to use a RewriteRule instead of RedirectPermanent for the second operation too. This would look something like this:

```
# Perform this redirect first
RewriteRule "^coaching/Run to live$" http://www.example.com/coaching [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^coaching/([^/]+)/?$ search_result.php?categoryName=$1  [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference (under certain conditions) is that using RedirectPermanent the HTTP response is 301 (Permanent Redirect) - telling the browser/crawler that the page has moved in a permanent way...
RewriteRule returns 302 (unless specified otherwise in the options) - and this means to the browser that this redirection is "temporary" and that at a future date this link will again serve the requested content.

Comment: I would ad that Redirect & RedirectPermanent are apache instructions, from mod_alias I think, that can handle basic redirects, rewrite rule are mod_rewrite things, that can do the same job and more complex things as well. Usually people does'nt know they can do simple redirect rules without mod_rewrite.